# if statement counter variable confusion javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

As a novice in javascript, I am having trouble writing an If statement, with an event happening after the fourth turn. I want the alert to pop up after the  user has clicked four options. I added the counter variable "turns" to the output so I can see if it has been counting correctly but it does not.

```
var question1 = new Array();
var turns = 0;

window.onload = function () {
    var eSelect = document.getElementById('question1');
    var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('displayresponse');
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
    eSelect.onchange = function () {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = options[eSelect.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        var ol = document.getElementById("appendedtext");
        ol.appendChild(li);
        question1.push(li.innerHTML);
        var x = document.getElementById("display");
        x.innerHTML = question1 + turns;
        turns + 1;
    }
    if (eSelect.selectedIndex == 3) {
        optOtherReason.style.display = 'block';
        turns - 1;
    }
    if (turns = 4) {
        alert("hey your turn is over")
    }
}
```

```
<select id="question1" name="question">
    <option value="x">Reason1</option>
    <option value="y">Reason2</option>
    <option value="other">Otherreason</option>
    <option value="none">None</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="displayresponse" style="display:none;">If you did not see a choice here, you may search for other sites.</div>
<ol id="appendedtext"></ol>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare two expression you need to use `==` :

```
if ( turns == 4)
```

Also, `turns` is a variable, so to sum/substract one you should use:

```
turns += 1
turns -= 1
```

Or, as pointed out in comments, you could also use:

```
turns++;
turns--;
```

Comment: What is **2 '='**? Do you mean `==`?

Comment: `evaluate an expression` Do you mean `compare two expressions`?

Comment: Also `--turns` or `++turns` are options. :-)

Comment: For reason the browser still completely ignores the all of my IF statements